# How to restrict the databases that a user sees in pgAdmin3?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

My local database server (PostgreSQL 9.4) contains several databases used by several distinct web apps. Each of the applications has a user account and that account is the owner of the appropriate database.

I have defined in pgAdmin3 several connections (one per web app user account) and I do not get the behavior that I get with phpMyAdmin in similar setups using MySQL: a user can only see the database for which they have access rights.

This has not bothered me over the years, but I finally got to asking the question: is it possible to make it so that a user account connected to a database server in pgAdmin3 can only see the limited set of databases that they have access to?

My objective is that one restricted user account won't see the entire list of available databases.

NOTE: Revoking the *TEMP* and *CONNECT* privileges granted by default to `public` was not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can revoke the `SELECT` privilege on `pg_catalog.pg_database` from `PUBLIC`, then normal users cannot get the list of databases.

But that will probably cause errors with tools like pgAdmin that expect to be able to get data from that table.